# Can't call class function from a template function class inside a template class

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I am trying to create a pattern where an abstract class has several methods where all get the same member. The derived implementation is on a specific member type and the pattern should redundant the need to downcast the types.

**The following is not working:**

Assume these type classes

```
//--------------
// Data classes
//--------------
class TypeA
{
    virtual int a() = 0;
};

class TypeB : public TypeA
{
    int a() override
    {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

Pattern:

```
//-------------------
// Base action class.
//-------------------
class ExampleBase
{
public:
    virtual bool f1(TypeA& val) = 0;

    virtual bool f2(TypeA& val) = 0;
};

//----------------------------------
// Base specific Typed action class.
//----------------------------------
template<class T>
class ExampleSpecific1 : public ExampleBase
{
public:
    virtual bool specificF1(T& specificVal) = 0;

    virtual bool specificF2(T& specificVal) = 0;

    bool f1(TypeA& val) override
    {
        return fRunner<bool, specificF1>(val, false);
    }

    bool f2(TypeA& val) override
    {
        return fRunner<bool, specificF2>(val, false);
    }

private:

    // Run the specific function with the specific type
    template<class S, S (*pf)(T& val)>
    S fRunner(TypeA& val, S defaultValue)
    {
        S ret = defaultValue;
        T& specificVal = dynamic_cast<T&>(val);

        if (&specificVal != nullptr) {
            ret = pf(specificVal);
        }

        return ret;
    }
};
```

The implementation

```
//----------------------
// Class Implementation.
//----------------------
class ExampleImpl : public ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>
{
public:
    bool specificF1(TypeB& specificVal) override
    {
        // Do something
    }

    bool specificF2(TypeB& specificVal) override
    {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
//-----------
// Class Use.
//-----------
void main()
{
    ExampleImpl impl;
    TypeB myVal;

    TypeA& myBaseVal = myVal;
    impl.f1(myBaseVal);
    impl.f2(myBaseVal);
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
error C2672: 'ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>::fRunner': no matching overloaded function found
note: while compiling class template member function 'bool ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>::f2(TypeA &)'
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>::f2(TypeA &)' being compiled
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>' being compiled
error C2975: 'pf': invalid template argument for 'ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>::fRunner', expected compile-time constant expression
note: see declaration of 'pf'
```

**A function template that does work (when the function is not inside a class):**

Based on the previous example:

```
template<class T, bool (*pf1)(T& Val), bool (*pf2)(T& Val)>
class ExampleSpecific2 : public ExampleBase
{
public:
    bool f1(TypeA& val) override
    {
        bool ret = false;
        T& specificVal = dynamic_cast<T&>(val);

        if (&specificVal != nullptr) {
            ret = pf1(specificVal);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    bool f2(TypeA& val) override
    {
        bool ret = false;
        T& specificVal = dynamic_cast< T&>(val);

        if (&specificVal != nullptr) {
            ret = pf2(specificVal);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

External functions:

```
bool extF1(TypeB& val)
{
    // Do something.
}

bool extF2(TypeB& val)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Useage:

```
//-----------
// Class Use.
//-----------
void main()
{
    TypeB myVal;
    TypeA& myBaseVal = myVal;

    ExampleSpecific2<TypeB, extF1, extF2> impl2;

    impl2.f1(myBaseVal);
    impl2.f2(myBaseVal);
}
```

In the example that does not work, I can implement the down cast in each of the implementation and then it works, but it is ugly and is not generic. In the working example I want the function to be in the internal implementation of the class and not external to it, this is important in more complicated scenarios, where the base class is calling several of the derived methods.

- BTW I don't like this post Title, if you have a better suggestion that I like, this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note :

1. `main` should return an int, not void
2. `if (&specificVal != nullptr)` will be always true, reference cannot be null.

I am not sur why you got this error message, with `gcc` I got :

```
no matching member function for call to 'fRunner'
```

Because `pf` type was `bool (ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>::*)(TypeB &)` which didn't match with `S (*pf)(T& val)`. The first one need an class object.

So I just use the C++17 auto :

```
template<class S, auto pf>
S fRunner(TypeA& val, S defaultValue){...}
```

But you can use the full type if you want.

Next We need to call the member function. I don't like (nor remember) the member function call syntaxe, so I just use `std::invoke` of C++17. (see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

Live : https://wandbox.org/permlink/rEqgLSwSjEfqRK2o

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//--------------
// Data classes
//--------------
class TypeA
{
    virtual int a() = 0;
};

class TypeB : public TypeA
{
    int a() override
    {
        return 5;
    }
};



//-------------------
// Base action class.
//-------------------
class ExampleBase
{
public:
    virtual bool f1(TypeA& val) = 0;

    virtual bool f2(TypeA& val) = 0;
};

//----------------------------------
// Base specific Typed action class.
//----------------------------------
template<class T>
class ExampleSpecific1 : public ExampleBase
{
private:

    // Run the specific function with the specific type
    template<class S, auto pf>
    S fRunner(TypeA& val, S defaultValue)
    {
        S ret = defaultValue;
        T& specificVal = dynamic_cast<T&>(val);
 
        ret = std::invoke(pf, *this, specificVal);


        return ret;
    }
public:
    virtual bool specificF1(T& specificVal) = 0;

    virtual bool specificF2(T& specificVal) = 0;

    bool f1(TypeA& val) override
    {
        return this->fRunner<bool, &ExampleSpecific1<T>::specificF1>(val, false);
    }

    bool f2(TypeA& val) override
    {
        return this->fRunner<bool, &ExampleSpecific1<T>::specificF2>(val, false);
    }


};

// Class Implementation.
//----------------------
class ExampleImpl : public ExampleSpecific1<TypeB>
{
public:
    bool specificF1(TypeB& ) override
    {
       std::cout << "specificF1" << std::endl;
       return true;
    }

    bool specificF2(TypeB& ) override
    {
        std::cout << "specificF2" << std::endl;
       return true;
    }
};



//-----------
// Class Use.
//-----------
int main()
{
    ExampleImpl impl;
    TypeB myVal;

    TypeA& myBaseVal = myVal;
    impl.f1(myBaseVal);
    impl.f2(myBaseVal);
}
```

Pre C++17 : https://wandbox.org/permlink/HSGMy4zb4TgusESf

```
template<class S, S (ExampleSpecific1<T>::*pf)(T &)> // full type since auto is C++ 17
S fRunner(TypeA& val, S defaultValue)
{
     S ret = defaultValue;
     T& specificVal = dynamic_cast<T&>(val);
     ret = (this->*pf)(specificVal); // Ugly pre 17 

     return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is a simplified example, in real life there is no main function at all - it is just for demo purposes, I have not written a main function for years, so this one is on me. The `&specificVal != nullptr` actually does work, tested this many, many times with failed `dynaic_cast`and I did not get past the `if` statement (In any case this is not the point). The code works perfectly when the methodology of 'fRunner' is incorporated directly into the implementation of `f1` and `f2` as is done in the second example (`ExampleSpecific2`).

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast : " If the cast fails and new-type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type std::bad_cast.". In general a reference cannot be null, if you `dynamic_cast` a pointer, then yes, you have to check

Comment: Appart from that, If my answer does not do what you want, can you provide a live example ? I have rebuild your code with everything before "I get the following compilation error". And if it does, pls mark as resolved

Comment: With your code I get: `note: 'auto' in non-type template parameters requires at least '/std:c++17'` (We are still in VS2017) - So I changed the auto to my previous definition, and run into the same issue.  The point is that I get this compilation error. Hence, the only working example I can give is one where the 'fRunner' is not used. If this is good enough I can add it! As for the `dynamic_cast` I'll check this, may be we never pass a class which can't be downcast and you might be right.

Comment: "So I changed the auto to my previous definition". AFAIU that the problem. I have had a pre 17 solution without `auto` nor `invoke`. Tell me if it works

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. I have created a working example in https://wandbox.org/permlink/ObpGpNVdCsvsVYvP without the template function. BTW I did not know this sandbox tool. Kudos, just for this I will up vote you answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221263/discussion-between-martin-morterol-and-juv).